# Data set query, database or searching in file?

Tags: python, sql, database, flask

I have a set of files, ~300 files each with 50,000 lines. Each line is a string tag with a binary value (1 or 0). All files have the same entries, but different binary values. Example of a file below.

```
Tag1    0
Tag2    1
...
Tag50000    0
```

I intend to build a Python Flask web tool with several functions that will compare two "files" or find every "file" with where a specific tag is 1. The other option is to search all files in the directory for comparison. I believe that using some SQL database would be incredibly powerful for querying however I have some questions. This is how I imagine the database would be structured, but I could be wrong.

```
Filename1   Tag1-value  Tag2-value  ... Tag50000-value
Filename2   Tag1-value  Tag2-value  ... Tag50000-value
...
Filename300 Tag1-value  Tag2-value  ... Tag50000-value
```

I have some experience with SQLAlchemy for Flask but from my previous use, each database value would need a separate declaration in my application's models file, which seems very inefficient for 50,000 characteristics. Is it possible to enter all of this data into a different SQL database and still access it in flask?

Here is what how I believe the model would have to be setup, and if necessary I would write out all 50,000 tags but I have to believe there is a simpler way to do this.

```py
class Dataset(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    filename = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)

    tag1 = db.Column(db.Boolean)    # or tag1 = db.Column(db.Integer)
    tag2 = db.Column(db.Boolean)    # or tag2 = db.Column(db.Integer)
    # ...
    tag50000 = db.Column(db.Boolean)    # or tag50000 = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

Comment: Can you clarify this... *each database value would need a separate declaration in my application's models file, which seems very inefficient for 50,000 characteristics* ...is there 50000 tags? Are tags a string or something else? the model would surely be tag, val, file...1 definition

Comment: couldn’t it be id, file, tagName, val? Makes it 15,000,000 rows though

Comment: @AndrewAllen Thanks I updated my question to include a code snippet. There are 300 files each with the same 50,000 string tags however the value at each tag can be either 1 or 0. This is the format of how I have learned SQLAlchemy. I guess it could be and I could give it a try. Not sure how run time would be affected but I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Having 50000 columns in the table, one column for each tag, is unrealistic. [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-685230CF-63F5-4C5A-B8B0-037C566BDA76.htm#REFRN0043) allows for 1000 columns per one table, [MySql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/5.6/en/column-count-limit.html) for 4096, others DB have similar restrictions. You need a different model - a table with 3 colums: `FileId, TagName, Value(0/1)`

Comment: @krokodilko Thank you for your help, that's about what I ended up implementing. I wasn't sure on the limitations of number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my current working solution, not elegant and there may be a better optimized way. Two tables, first for each "filename" and second for each tag.

Table 1:

```
FileId  ReferencetoTag
```

Table 2:

```
TagId   Value(0/1)  FileId(ForeignKey)
```

```py
class Sample(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # Sample_id and filename are synonymous
    Sample_id = db.Column(db.String(10), index=True, unique=True)
    tags = db.relationship('Tag', backref='name', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<File_id {}>'.format(self.File_id)


class Tag(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    tag_id = db.Column(db.String(20), index=True)

    value = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    sample_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sample.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Gene_id {}>'.format(self.gene_id)
```